# liferay portlet spring mvc form is empty

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a problem. The form submit is empty.

```
public class Customer implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String address;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

PortletViewController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class PortletViewController {


    @RenderMapping
    public String viewHomePage(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) {

        return "test/view";
    }

    @RenderMapping(params = "action=showForm")
    public String viewByParameter(Map<String, Object> map) {

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        map.put("customer", customer);
        return "test/form";
    }

    @RenderMapping(params = "action=success")
    public String viewSuccess() {
        return "test/success";
    }

    @ActionMapping(value = "handleCustomer")
    public void getCustomerData(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,
            ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse,
            Model model) {

        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action", "success");

        model.addAttribute("successModel", customer);
    }
}
```

form.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:actionURL var="submitFormURL" name="handleCustomer"/>
<form:form name="customer" method="post" modelAttribute="customer" action="   <%=submitFormURL.toString() %>">
<br/>
<table style="margin-left:80px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstName"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="middleName">Middle Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="middleName"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="age"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="address">Address</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="address"></form:input></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form:form>
```

success.jsp

```
<div>
<h3>Form submitted successfully</h3>
</div>

<div>
First Name:
${successModel.firstName}
</div>

<div>
Middle Name:
${successModel.middleName}
</div>

<div>
Last Name:
${successModel.lastName}
</div>

<div>
Age:
${successModel.age}
</div>

<div>
Address:
${successModel.address}
</div>
```

view.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:renderURL var="renderURL">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="showForm"/>
</portlet:renderURL>

<h3> Spring Form Submission Demo</h3>

<br/><br/>

<a href="<%=renderURL.toString()%>">Go to Form Page</a>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<web-app
    version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet-application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

portlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>test</portlet-name>
        <display-name>test</display-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet/test-portlet.xml</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>test</title>
            <short-title>test</short-title>
            <keywords>test</keywords>
        </portlet-info>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

portlet-application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
>
    <context:annotation-config/>


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

test-portlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
>
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.**" />
</beans>
```

Can someone help me?

Why is the Customer submit empty?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. In liferay-portlet.xml following must be added.

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```